# Not able to collect firewall ng fw.log contiuously using LEA

Tags: checkpoint

Our local application will try to get event data from Checkpoint *fw.log* using LEA. Our firewall version is **"Firewall-1 NG"**. Our application is not able to get events continuously(not collecting for few hours) though checkpoint is generating logs continuously. In case of **"Firewall-1 4.1"** version collecting fine. Any information would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

could you send more details about your code? Are you developing all integration using LEA libraries from Check Point or are you using fw-loggrabber (https://github.com/certego/fw1-loggrabber/wiki/Configure-and-run-FW1-LogGrabber)

We use fw-loggrabber in online and offline mode. Using Offline mode you can be affected by log rotation. If you don't need old data, you can read in realtime, configuring ONLINE mode.

We list available files and download it, but if you want to get it in real time you could use log-grabber to:

At the documentation above you can find:

> ONLINE_MODE= when using online mode, FW1-LogGrabber starts retrieving logging data from the end of the specified logfile and displays all future log entries; this mode is mainly used for continuously processing FW1 log data; if you disable online mode, FW1-LogGrabber quits after having displayed the last log entry.
>
> FW1_TYPE= choose which version of FW1 to connect to; for Checkpoint FW-1 5.0 you have to specify NG and for Checkpoint FW-1 4.1 you have to specify 2000.